What is a reasonable substitute for Korean soybean paste (also known as "Doenjang " or 된장 or 된醬)?
Suppose that you are preparing a korean recipe, but you do not have any fermented soy bean paste (된장). What is a reasonable alternative?

Doenjang is fairly similar to miso, in ingredients, taste, and (distantly) how it’s made. It’s an entirely acceptable substitute. Shiro miso is probably the closest variety.

Mexican style refried beans mixed with salt.
Doenjong is very salty, so quite a lot of salt must be added to the re-fried beans in order to achieve a similar flavor.
I have not perfected the ratio of salt to refried beans.
I hope that other users of this website will write better answers. If someone finds an ideal ratio of salt to refried beans, then their answer will undoubtedly receive more upvotes than this preliminary answer.
I hope to see your answers rise above mine, but half a loaf of bread is better than none, so there is a preliminary answer here.

If you go this route, consider adding MSG rather than more salt.

the fermentation of the paste is very important to the taste, you're probably better off with another fermented product than unfermented beans.
